# How to add markers on the map

Tags: flutter, here-api

I'm using the Flutter SDK Version 4.3.1.0.

I would like to display markers on the map and I found that this would be possible via:

```
final String positionMarkerPath = 'assets/markers/marker.png';

mapScene.addMapMarker(
  MapMarker(
    geoCoordinates,
    MapImage.withFilePathAndWidthAndHeight(positionMarkerPath, 32, 32)));
```

When using this method I constantly get errors

```
E/CL_geoviz( 9632): [ERROR] CL_geoviz - Can't find image 'file:///assets/markers/marker.png' in asset repository.
E/CL_geoviz( 9632): [ERROR] CL_geoviz - Can't load image file 'file:///assets/markers/marker.png' to memory stream.
```

Now, the method `MapImage.withFilePathAndWidthAndHeight` is documented as follows in the SDK:

`Creates a new map image from the provided path to the SVG Tiny image` which is weird because I thought that Flutter doesn't even support SVG out of the box. Could that be an issue? Or what am I doing wrong here?

I tried using an SVG, Vector Drawable and a png, tried fully qualifying the path, nothing works

Comment: It is not necessary to add tag information to the title. The tag system works extermely well and doesn't need help. It's unnecessary clutter to add *HERE SDK for Flutter* as the prefix of every single question.

Comment: Did you ass the image directory in your `pubspec.yaml` file ? @luckyhandler

Comment: @T.TSage yes, the pubspec.yaml is correctly setup. These assets work in regular flutter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `MapImage.withFilePathAndWidthAndHeight` says that it is only for **SVG Tiny** format. But it currently does not seem to work as the HERE SDK for Flutter is still in Beta state.

You can instead load and add PNG files as marker like this:

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/some_image.png');
MapImage image = MapImage.withPixelDataAndImageFormat(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), ImageFormat.png);
MapMarker marker = MapMarker(geoCoordinates, image);
hereMapController.mapScene.addMapMarker(marker);
```

The assets directory needs to be specified in the `pubspec.yaml`.